# $A$ be $n\times n$ matrix such that $A^2=I$

Tags: linear-algebra

$A$ be $n\times n$ matrix such that $A^2=I$, we need to show any $n\times 1$ vector can be expressed as a sum atmost two eigen vectors of $A$, I have no idea how to proceed, and  nothing was given about the entries of $A$, Please help!

Comment: Note that $A^2=I\Rightarrow (A+I)(A-I)=0$. Do you know to compute the eigenvalues and eigenvectors?

Comment: $1,-1$ are eigen values according to you?, but how come $n\times n$ has only $2$ eigen values, Is $x^2-1=0$ are you saying Char poly?or Minpoly?

Comment: The eigenvalues are roots of a polynomial and it can have only two roots (this is called multiplicity).

Comment: I can understand!so $1,-1$ are only eigen values with some multiplicty! which Can not be said from the given data right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\textbf{Hint:}$

Start by proving that the sum of any two eigenvectors of a given eigenvalue $\lambda$ is an eigenvector for $\lambda$ (with the exception of when the sum is the null vector), for any given matrix.

Then recall that if a matrix is diagonalizable, then there exists a basis of eigenvectors of that matrix.

Finally, after proving that your matrix $A$ is diagonalizable, somehow use the fact that it has   two eigenvalues.

If you wish you can generalize to the case where the matrix has $k$ eigenvalues.

Answer (score 1):

If $x=0$, then $x$ is the sum of $v$ and $-v$ for any eigenvector $v$ of $A$.

If $x\not=0$, let $u=(x+Ax)/2$ and $v=(x-Ax)/2$. Then $x=u+v,\, Au=u$ and $Av=-v$. Prove that $u$ and $v$ cannot be both zero and hence each of them, if nonzero, is an eigenvector of $A$.